# How can I expose a port from ASP.NET Core in Docker linux container in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, docker-compose, containers

I have several ASP.NET Core services defined in `docker-compose`. I need to be able to expose port in the `host` network (I use linux containers on Docker for Windows 18.03.0-ce).

Sample:

- Services C1 and C2 are running in containers.
- Service H3 is running directly in the host, not in container.
- All services (C1, C2 and H3) must be accesible to each other.

I don't know how to setup networking for services C1 and C2 in `docker-compose`. I tried this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  c1:
    image: <some image name>
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: <path to dockerfile>
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development      
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://localhost:9084
    ports:
      - "9084:9084"
    network_mode: "host"

  c2:
    image: <some image name>
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: <path to dockerfile>
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development      
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://localhost:9085
    ports:
      - "9085:9085"
    network_mode: "host"
```

I see this in the console when containers are started:

```
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://localhost:9085
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

But I cannot connect them from the host. `netstat -an` doesn't show these ports, `telnet localhost 9084` fails.

This is output from `docker inspect` for that container:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "SandboxID": "df480d4d68cb109dc6b85f689f8b210a9f74e650c48a343cdd3d11eb3d10bec7",
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "Ports": {},
    "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/default",
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
    "EndpointID": "",
    "Gateway": "",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "",
    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "MacAddress": "",
    "Networks": {
        "host": {
            "IPAMConfig": null,
            "Links": null,
            "Aliases": null,
            "NetworkID": "324d836f54fa685d56b416f01a18e3e75f88d4516dafac43bb1a4ff760a2b67a",
            "EndpointID": "9212f6a01e142ef9fb71116c9fe03c37567c60ed8a2add91fe28bf0bd6de001a",
            "Gateway": "",
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "",
            "DriverOpts": null
        }
    }
}
```

When I remove `network_mode: "host"` configuration from `docker-compose` (network is then `bridge` as default), I get this message form the application:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
Unable to bind to http://localhost:9084 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Error -99 EADDRNOTAVAIL address not available'.
```

Can you help me to setup the network configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem:

- I do not set any network in `docker-compose` (the generated *_default with `bridge` driver is used) - removed `network_mode`.
- I removed `ASPNETCORE_URLS` ENV variable in `docker-compose`.
- APS.NET Core applications use port 80 (inside container).
- Port 80 is exposed (for example) as 9084 to be accessible from the host.
- Application is configured to use (for example) `localhost:9085`.
- `docker-compose` uses environment variable to override the endpoint to `host.docker.internal.9085`.

Now, all services running in containers use `host.docker.internal` and some port 
to connect to some other service, so these services can connect other services running in a container or directly in the host.

Services running in the host use `localhost` and some port, so they can connect other services running in the host or in the container.

This is sample of `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  c1:
    image: <some image name>
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: <path to dockerfile>
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    env_file:
      - docker-compose.override.env
    ports:
      - "9084:80"

  c2:
    image: <some image name>
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: <path to dockerfile>
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    env_file:
      - docker-compose.override.env
    ports:
      - "9085:80"
```

Sample of `docker-compose.override.env` file:

```
ApiOptions__DomainModelApiBaseUrl=http://host.docker.internal:9081/api
ApiOptions__SearchApiBaseUrl=http://host.docker.internal:9088/api
```

Now I am able to run the same service in container or from Visual Studio and debug it.